# Как убрать некрасивый триггер woocommerce? Display none не помогает

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

вот этот тригер увеличени изображения очень хочется убрать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы удалить триггер, добавьте в `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css` вашей темы:

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger img.emoji {
    display: none !important;
}
```